# SSIS OLEDB destination with SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, oledb

I have a simple SSIS package with a data flow task with ADO.NET source & destination:

[image]

Normally, I would just select 'table or view' on the OLEDB destination, but although the connection is correct it's not showing me any table names.

So: I have to use SQL command to insert rows in the OLE DB destination. That destination is a DB2 database.

My question: how can I write this sql statement to insert everything from the ANO NET source into the destination table?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the SQL Command Text, Just write

```
SELECT * FROM TableName --Here tablename is the destination table name.
```

And go to the Mapping and map the appropriate columns if it is not already mapped.

Comment: totally not logical if you think about it, but simple & it works :)

Comment: @PoeHaH the SELECT command in this case is not to retrieve data but to retrieve columns metadata from the query result.

Comment: And how would you add "Keep identity" option in SQL command?